# Why is this code not returning true ever?

Tags: java, methods

Okay so I have this method and the comments I inserted should explain everything I am not sure what I have done to make it inaccurate. I ran through a few tests and only got true once.

```
//This method checks to see if a player has made a successful guess in the game of Hang Man
//For example, if the parameters are as follows:
//     letter: "e"
//     wordAsArray: {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}
//     guessed: {true, false, false, false, true}
//Then the guessed array would be changed to:
//      guessed: {true, true, false, false, true}
//And the method would return false
//Parameters:   letter - the letter that the user has just guessed
//              wordAsArray - an array of individual letters that are to be guessed
//              guessed - array of boolean values; a true value means the corresponding letter has been guessed
//Returns:  true - if letter matches an unguessed letter in wordAsArray
//          false - otherwise
public static boolean guess(String letter, String[] wordAsArray, boolean[] guessed) {
    boolean appearsAtLeastOnce=false;
    for(int i = 0; i<wordAsArray.length;i++)
        if(letter.equalsIgnoreCase(wordAsArray[i])){
            guessed[i] = true;
            appearsAtLeastOnce=true;
        }
    return appearsAtLeastOnce;
```

Most times I am getting false which isn't what it should be. What is wrong here?
All recommendations are welcome!

Comment: This method should be easily testable with debugging. What happens when you try doing this?

Comment: your code seems right. try to log the values of the paremters to see what your method receives and what it returns. my guess would be that wordAsArray is not correct

Comment: re-run with the parameters with which you got true and analyze with the other parameters you pass in..

Comment: Why not use a `char` and a `char[]`?

Comment: i think what you intended to write was : "Returns:  true - if letter matches a _guessed_ letter in wordAsArray"

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing what you describe in the comment: (example given and comment(last line) contradict)

ex:

> letter:  "e"
>   wordAsArray: {"h",   "e",   "L",   "L",  "o"}
>   guessed:     {true, false, false, false, true}
>   returned guessed : {true, true, false, false, true}
>   returned boolean: true  //Which is not intended

Modified code would be:

```
public static boolean guess(String letter, String[] wordAsArray, boolean[] guessed) {
    boolean appearsAtLeastOnce=false;
    for(int i = 0; i<wordAsArray.length;i++)
        if(letter.equalsIgnoreCase(wordAsArray[i])){
            if(!guessed[i]){
              guessed[i] = true;                      
           }else{
              appearsAtLeastOnce = true;               
           }
        }
    return appearsAtLeastOnce;
}
```